# Trying to do numerical operations using LWC component but getting NaN as response in the output

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I'm trying to create a calculator component and it is working, the problem is the numbers are not properly parsed and I'm getting NaN as the response.

Here is the sample output I'm getting :

> Result of NaN+NaN is NaN

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Simple Calculator" icon-name="standard:formula">
        <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
            <lightning-layout-item size="12" padding="around-medium">
                <lightning-input type="integer" name ="firstNumber" onchange ={numberChangeHandler}></lightning-input>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item size="12" padding="around-medium">
                <lightning-input type="integer" name ="secondNumber" onchange ={numberChangeHandler}></lightning-input>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item size="12" padding="around-medium">
                <lightning-button-group>
                    <lightning-button label="Add" icon-name="utility:add" icon:position="right" onclick={addHandler}></lightning-button>
                    <lightning-button label="Subtract" icon-name="utility:dash" icon:position="right" onclick={subHandler}></lightning-button>
                    <lightning-button label="Multiply" icon-name="utility:close" icon:position="right" onclick={mutiplyHandler}></lightning-button>
                    <lightning-button label="Divide" icon-name="utility:magicwand" icon:position="right" onclick={divideHandler}></lightning-button>
                </lightning-button-group>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item size="12" padding="around-medium">
                <lightning-formatted-text value={currentResult} ></lightning-formatted-text>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class SimpleCalculator extends LightningElement {
@track currentResult;

    firstNumber = 0;
    secondNumber = 0;

    numberChangeHandler(event){
        const inputBoxName = event.target.name;
        if(inputBoxName === 'firstNumber'){
            this.firstNumber = parseInt(event.target.name);
        }else if(inputBoxName === 'secondNumber'){
            this.secondNumber = parseInt(event.target.name);
        }
    }

    addHandler(){
        const firstN = parseInt(this.firstNumber);
        const secondN = parseInt(this.secondNumber);

        this.currentResult = 'Result of '+firstN+'+'+secondN+' is '+(firstN+secondN);
    }

    subHandler(){
        const firstN = parseInt(this.firstNumber);
        const secondN = parseInt(this.secondNumber);

        this.currentResult = `Result of ${firstN} - ${secondN} is ${firstN-secondN}`;
    }

    mutiplyHandler(){
        const firstN = parseInt(this.firstNumber);
        const secondN = parseInt(this.secondNumber);

        this.currentResult = 'Result of '+firstN+'x'+secondN+' is '+(firstN*secondN);
    }

    divideHandler(){
        const firstN = parseInt(this.firstNumber);
        const secondN = parseInt(this.secondNumber);

        this.currentResult = `Result of ${firstN} / ${secondN} is ${firstN/secondN}`;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to parse the element name, instead of its value, and if you try to parse a string like `'firstNumber'` into an integer you'll get `NaN`.
You should also change the type of your [lightning-input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification) to `number`, `integer` isn't a valid value. The documentation lists every valid one.
Anyway since the default `step` is `1`, only integers will be valid values.
You can check its validity via `event.target.validity.valid`.
Moreover, as suggested by sfdcfox, you can avoid the if-else writing `this[inputBoxName] = parseInt(event.detail.value)`.

Change

```
numberChangeHandler(event) {
    const inputBoxName = event.target.name;
    if(inputBoxName === 'firstNumber'){
        this.firstNumber = parseInt(event.target.name);
    }else if(inputBoxName === 'secondNumber'){
        this.secondNumber = parseInt(event.target.name);
    }
}
```

To

```
numberChangeHandler(event){
    if (event.target.validity.valid) {
        const inputBoxName = event.target.name;
        this[inputBoxName] = parseInt(event.detail.value)
    } else {
        // handle the invalid input
    }
}
```

Making those input-filed required and checking the validity would take care of the `NaN` you'll get when an user erases the content of that field: `parseInt('')` returns `NaN`.

Finally there is no need to parse again those value in `addHandler`, `subHandler`, `mutiplyHandler` and `divideHandler`

Comment: P.S. You can write `this[inputBoxName] = parseInt(event.detail.value)` to avoid the if-else statements.